# HOW TO IMPROVE THE PERFORMANCE OF SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I asked before a question regarding to the query and thanks to the community I have got a solution. Now I would love to speed up my query (improve its performance).

This is my query. When I try to use it on python with psycopg on python it take an eternity to execute it. How can I speed it up? I have tried to group by customer id, zip_code and store and sum(spending) however it results with the query even more long. Appreciate all your solutions.

```
select * 
from spendings sp 
join store st on right(st.store, 6) = sp.store
join customer cu on cu.zip_code = replace(st.zip_code, ' ', '');
```

These are my 3 tables in PostgreSQL:

SPENDINGS:

```
store      |spending
-----------+---------
0000700551 |   $75
```

STORE:

```
store  | zip_code
-------+---------
700551 | XXP PDD
```

CUSTOMER:

```
id  | zip_code
----+----------
002 | XXPPDD
```

Comment: Have you run `ANALYZE` on the query? How long does it take? Since you mention `psycopg2`, are you sure the query is taking too long, not application code around it?

Comment: Your query does not have any filtering condition. That means you are retrieving all joined rows. If this is a reporting query it's OK if it takes time. If this is a transactional query it should only encompass a few rows and should be extremely fast. Please elaborate.

Comment: You could try an index on `store(right(store, 6))` and `store(, replace(zip_code, ' ', ''))` but I doubt this would make things much faster. The fact that you need to use different "keys" for a store in a different tables is not a good design to begin with.

Comment: Both your join conditions are not *sargable* and leave the query optimizer little choice but to perform a table scan on both tables. To improve performance and make use of indexes you need to **remove** the functions on the join predicates. Don't store *store* as a string if you need to join it with an integer and store *zip_code* either with or without a space in both tables.

Comment: This requires `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

Answer (score 1):

**This probably isn't much different than @a_horse_with_no_name 's suggestion, which is more direct, to just add function based indexes directly.**

I suppose the benefit is in hiding the mess from the query logic.

When the original column data can't be changed, we can use/add generated columns to automatically store the adjusted values, so that the join logic does not need to use functions at runtime, and can make use of indexes.

Note: The original question has mistakes in either the table data or the query logic.  I assumed the data shown was wrong and the query was correct.  The following concepts are the same, regardless of which `table.column` needs a generated alternative.

The adjusted query, where `norm_store` and `norm_zip` are generated/stored columns:

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7fbd765f01dc1da31bc8a370fefabd81)

```
select *
  from spendings sp 
  join store     st on st.norm_store = sp.store
  join customer  cu on cu.zip_code   = st.norm_zip
;
```

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE spendings (store varchar(20), spending decimal(7,2));

INSERT INTO spendings VALUES
   ('700551' ,   75.0)
;

CREATE TABLE store (
      store      varchar(20)
    , zip_code   varchar(10)
    , norm_store varchar( 6) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (right(store   , 6))         STORED
    , norm_zip   varchar(10) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (replace(zip_code, ' ', '')) STORED
);

-- Just examples of indexes which refer to generated columns
CREATE INDEX xxx1 ON store(norm_store);
CREATE INDEX xxx2 ON store(norm_zip  );
CREATE INDEX xxx3 ON store(norm_store, norm_zip  );

INSERT INTO store VALUES
   ('0000700551' ,   'XXP PDD')
;

CREATE TABLE customer (id varchar(20), zip_code varchar(10));

INSERT INTO customer VALUES
   ('002' ,   'XXPPDD')
;
```