# SQL: Match on date ranges across two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking for best practices when dealing with mappings that vary in time and are defined by `from` and `to` date fields. For example, take this sample [Postgres DB](https://github.com/vrajmohan/pgsql-sample-data/blob/master/employee/employees.dump) with employees info.

It has a mapping between employees and salaries that is valid for different date ranges:

```
> SELECT * FROM salaries LIMIT 5

|   emp_no |   salary | from_date   | to_date    |
|---------:|---------:|:------------|:-----------|
|    10001 |    60117 | 1986-06-26  | 1987-06-26 |
|    10001 |    62102 | 1987-06-26  | 1988-06-25 |
|    10001 |    66074 | 1988-06-25  | 1989-06-25 |
|    10001 |    66596 | 1989-06-25  | 1990-06-25 |
|    10001 |    66961 | 1990-06-25  | 1991-06-25 |
```

And a mapping between employees and titles:

```
> SELECT * FROM titles LIMIT 5

|   emp_no | title           | from_date   | to_date    |
|---------:|:----------------|:------------|:-----------|
|    10001 | Senior Engineer | 1986-06-26  | 9999-01-01 |
|    10002 | Staff           | 1996-08-03  | 9999-01-01 |
|    10003 | Senior Engineer | 1995-12-03  | 9999-01-01 |
|    10004 | Engineer        | 1986-12-01  | 1995-12-01 |
|    10004 | Senior Engineer | 1995-12-01  | 9999-01-01 |
```

What's the best way to map titles to salaries so I can, for instance, calculate average salaries per title. Note that an employee's salary may change without a title change and vice versa.

My current solution is to CROSS JOIN these tables with a table containing all possible dates if interest:

```sql
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT date_trunc('day', dd):: date AS the_date
FROM generate_series
        ( '1985-01-01'::timestamp 
        , '2003-01-01'::timestamp
        , '1 day'::interval) dd
),
daily_salaries AS (
    SELECT
        emp_no,
        salary,
        the_date
    FROM salaries t
    CROSS JOIN dates d
    WHERE the_date BETWEEN from_date AND to_date
),
daily_titles AS (
    SELECT
        emp_no,
        title,
        the_date
    FROM titles t
    CROSS JOIN dates d
    WHERE the_date BETWEEN from_date AND to_date
)
SELECT
    title,
    AVG(salary) AS avg_salary
FROM daily_salaries
INNER JOIN daily_titles USING (emp_no, the_date)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

But this seems terribly inefficient. What's a better way to accomplish this?

---

Edit: As Luuk mentioned in his answer, the problem with the query above is that the CROSS JOIN will generate a very large number of records. The crux of the question is how to avoid expanding salaries and titles over days for each employee while still associating an employee's salary to only the period in which they held a title.

The general question is how to merge over arbitrary time periods defined by a start and end without dealing with every day in the intervals, if at all possible.

Comment: "But this seems terribly inefficient" WHY ?  (Do I really have to download the dump, and try it to know if performance is bad? )

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate of: [HOW TO IMPROVE THE PERFORMANCE OF SQL QUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69425887/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

It is, a bit unclear why you are selecting from 2844047 records (`select count(*) from salaries`), and multiplying the number of results by 365 (for every day in the existing year), resulting in a temporary result of 1038077155+ records (`+`, because some year have more than 365 days...). Finally you are calculating the `avg_salary`, which will always be the same for all of the 365 days in that year.

I do think there is no need to generate_series for all individual dates, and this query should give the correct results:

```
select 
   t2.title, 
   avg(avg_salary) 
from (select 
         emp_no, 
         avg(salary) avg_salary 
      from salaries 
      group by emp_no) x 
inner join titles t2 on t2.emp_no=x.emp_no 
group by 1 order by 2 desc;
```

In above query I did not select from_date and/or to_date, because that will be left as a TODO for you

Results of above query:

```
       title        |        avg
--------------------+--------------------
 Senior Staff       | 69119.550582564534
 Staff              | 66956.829691848575
 Manager            | 66044.384223847367
 Senior Engineer    | 59144.768351940127
 Engineer           | 57244.458456267581
 Technique Leader   | 57034.814130272188
 Assistant Engineer | 56963.530432485845
(7 rows)
```

EDIT:

First you need to get the salary of an employee with the correct starting date and ending date, this deals with changing functions somewhere during the year

```
select 
    s.emp_no, 
    s.salary ,
    t.title,
    case when t.from_date >=s.from_date  then t.from_date else s.from_date end StartSal,
    case when t.from_date >=s.from_date  then s.to_date else case when t.to_date>s.to_date then s.to_date else t.to_date end end EndSal
from salaries s 
left join titles t on s.emp_no =t.emp_no and s.from_date <t.to_date  and s.to_date >t.from_date 
-- where s.emp_no =10005 and extract(year from s.from_date) in(1995,1996,1997)
order by s.emp_no, StartSal
```

example output (with the WHERE enabled):

```
emp_no|salary|title       |startsal  |endsal    |
------+------+------------+----------+----------+
 10005| 88448|Staff       |1995-09-11|1996-09-10|
 10005| 88063|Staff       |1996-09-10|1996-09-12|
 10005| 88063|Senior Staff|1996-09-12|1997-09-10|
 10005| 89724|Senior Staff|1997-09-10|1998-09-10|
```

When you want to know the average salary on 1996-01-01, you can do:

```
select title, round(avg(salary),2)
from (
select 
    s.emp_no, 
    s.salary ,
    t.title,
    case when t.from_date >=s.from_date  then t.from_date else s.from_date end StartSal,
    case when t.from_date >=s.from_date  then s.to_date else case when t.to_date>s.to_date then s.to_date else t.to_date end end EndSal
from salaries s 
left join titles t on s.emp_no =t.emp_no and s.from_date <t.to_date  and s.to_date >t.from_date 
order by s.emp_no, StartSal
) sal
where '1996-01-01'::date between StartSal and EndSal
group by title;
```

output:

```
title             |round   |
------------------+--------+
Engineer          |55341.77|
Senior Engineer   |61998.56|
Manager           |67784.00|
Assistant Engineer|54692.42|
Staff             |64678.06|
Senior Staff      |72139.55|
Technique Leader  |58156.86|
```

P.S. There is one small error in this, because the to_date is the same as the start_date. I did not handle this in this script.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem here is that this solution is not taking into account the periods in which an employee held a title and had a particular salary. For example, if an employee has two titles over time, and multiple salary levels, this query will average all the salaries and assign this average to both titles, when in reality different titles are associated with different pays.